# Collision Detection In Sprite Kit Not Detecting Collision

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsworld

I'm creating a game which will need to use a lot of collision detection and i'm only learning about it today.

Now I have two `SKSpriteNodes` but one is a child of an `SKNode`. The `SKSpriteNode` without a parent is called `character` and the sprite with the parent is called `buildingStructure`.

Now `character`'s category is `static const uint32_t playerCategory = 0x1 << 20;` and `buildingStructure`'s category is `_buildingStructureCategory = 0x1 << 0;`. `buildingStructure`'s category is set in another class `map.m` through a `@property`.

The variables pass over correctly to another class called `main.m` (which is where the `character`category is set). I create `character` with a method, setting his physics body, position and so on.

***`character`'s properties***

```
character.name = @"character";
character.size = CGSizeMake(250, 400);
character.zPosition = 500;
character.position = CGPointMake(self.scene.size.width/2, self.scene.size.height/2+200);
character.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:character.size];
character.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
character.physicsBody.density = 0.1;
character.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
character.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = playerCategory;
character.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = categoryBitManager.buildingStructureCategory;
```

***`buildingStructure`'s properties***

```
buildingStructure.name = @"buildingStructure";
buildingStructure.position = CGPointMake(building.position.x, building.position.y);
buildingStructure.size = CGSizeMake(500, 400);
buildingStructure.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

buildingStructure.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = _buildingStructureCategory;
```

On the other hand `buildingStructure` doesn't have a set `physicsBody` because I want `character` to pass through `buildingStructure` but I also want it to detect when `character` is 'on top' of `buildingStructure` to perform an action.

Since `buildingStructure` doesn't have a defined `physicsBody` is this what's causing `didBeginContact:contact` to not recognise the collision contact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **physicsBody** property of an **SKNode** *(or subclass of)* is **nil** by default. Yes give the buildingStructure a physics body and correctly configure it to achieve the desired behaviour.

To get the desired behaviour between two physics bodies, first understand that there are ***'collisions'*** and there are ***'contacts'***. **SKPhysicsBody** has two properties named **collisionBitMask** and **contactTestBitMask**.

For **collisionBitMask** the default value is 0xFFFFFFFF (all bits set), and for **contactTestBitMask** the default value is 0x00000000 (all bits cleared). You can see that by defaults every physics body will collide with others but there will be no contact.

A collision is where you want the physics simulation to affect the body in question, where a contact is where you want to be notified so you can do something. So this will call **didBeginContact:**

I suggest setting the **collisionBitMask** for both bodies to 0 (so their physics is not affected and pass through one another). Then set the **contactTestBitMask** property of character to that of the building like this-

```
character.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = categoryBitManager.buildingStructureCategory;
```

Comment: just figured this out for myself before, this sums it all up thanks. I also had to set `buildingStructure`'s `collisionBitMask` to `0x0` otherwise when `character` and `buildingStructure` collided `character` would push `buildingStructure` around.